# Python global variables - something missin

Tags: python, global-variables

I've a question on global variable, I've defined the following function but I do not understand why both myfunc() and myfunc3() work but not myfunc1() and  myfunc2():

```
x = "awesome"
global z
z = 50
y = 1


def myfunc():
    print("Python is " + x)

def myfunc1():
    z = z + 1
    print(y)

def myfunc2():
    y = y + 1
    print(y)

def myfunc3():
    global y
    y = y + 1
    print(y)

myfunc()

try:
    myfunc1()
except:
    print('wrong')

try:
    myfunc2()
except:
    print('wrong')

myfunc3()
```

Comment: Your functions that work either just read a global variable, or explicitly state that a variable is global before assigning to it. Your functions that don't work are trying to assign to a global without explicitly stating it is global.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python - `myfunc1` and `myfunc2` are using implicitly local variables and not the global `z` or `y`.

Comment: because you are not defining y inside your functions to make it run you should call global y inside each function like you did in func3

Comment: Thank you! Coming from MATLAB this was a bit tricky

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.